# Cómo hacer transaction entre fragments utilizando navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo hacer transaction entre fragments utilizando navigation drawer?

Estoy haciendo una app y estoy utlizando navigation drawer pero no sé cómo hacer la transaction entre fragment. El primer fragment me lo ejecuta si tengo mi primera pantalla blanca, si contiene algo se ve mal y la segunda de plano se detiene la app. estoy utilizando este código

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragmnet = null;


        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action}
                fragmnet = new fragment_home();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                fragmnet = new fragment_sesion();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }


        if (fragmnet != null){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.contenedor,fragmnet);
                            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código parece estar bien, asegúrate que el contenedor del fragment es el adecuado `R.id.contenedor`. También te recomiendo cambiar el `ft.commit()` por `ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()`

Añade el código de tu layout y el código que usas cuando añades el primer fragment a `R.id.contenedor` con `FragmentTransaction.add()` para ver que puede estar mal